# JVM Verify Error 'Illegal type at constant pool'

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am currently writing my own compiler and I am trying to compile the following code:

```
List[String] list = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
list stream map((String s) => s.toUpperCase())
System out println list
```

The compiler has no problem parsing, linking or compiling the code, but when it comes to executing it, the JVM throws the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 40 in class dyvil.test.Main
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dyvil/test/Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @29: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 40 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    ...
```

I tried to use `javap` to find the problem, and this is the instruction `@29`:

```
29: invokevirtual #40 // InterfaceMethod java/util/Collection.stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
```

And the entry in the Constant Pool (also using `javap`):

```
#37 = Utf8               stream
#38 = Utf8               ()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
#39 = NameAndType        #37:#38 // stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
#40 = InterfaceMethodref #36.#39 // java/util/Collection.stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
```

When opening the class with the Eclipse Class File Viewer, the line where `@29` should be reads:

```
Class Format Exception
```

and all following instructions are not shown anymore (except for Locals, ...). However, the ASM Bytecode Plugin writes

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/Collection.stream ()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
```

at that line, which appears to be valid. What am I doing wrong / missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. The error lies here:

```
invokevirtual #40 // InterfaceMethod
      ^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^
```

I am using invoke**virtual** on an **interface** method, which is generally not a good idea. However I think that the error thrown by the verifier should be a bit more clear about what is actually wrong.

Comment: This is maybe worth submitting as a compiler bug.

Comment: Oh, I see that it's your compiler, not *javac*. In that case send the bug report to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

With ASM you will see this error because of an incorrect `isInterface` flag. The argument `isInterface` of `visitMethodInsn` refers to the target/owner/destination and not the current context.

i.o.w when using `INVOKEVIRTUAL`, `isInterface` is false.

see [issue here](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/issues/317832) for more details.